# Update JLabel Display with Jtextfield, Jcombobox, Jradiobutton and JCheckbox input (ALL OF THEM TOGETHER)

Tags: java, actionlistener, jlabel, jtextfield, jcombobox

I am trying to update my JLabel based on all of the inputs listed in the title. I can get it to update for the Jradiobuttons, and Jcheckboxes, but not for anything else. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

Comment: You've posted a lot of code and a little explanation -- that's backwards. Post less code (get rid of code not relevant to your problem), and post *lot more explanation* so that we can fully understand your problem. Also, please fix your indentation so that your code is readable. The else blocks should be indented the same as the corresponding if block, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code with proper indentation. See the one example from your code

```
                    if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
                    {
                        totalAmountOwed += breakfast;    
                        //set the total Amount owed, and format it with money format.
                        lblAmountOwed.setText("$" + moneyFormat.format(totalAmountOwed));
                    } else
                            totalAmountOwed -= breakfast;
                            lblAmountOwed.setText("$" + moneyFormat.format(totalAmountOwed));
```

In this case lblAmountOwed.setText("$" + moneyFormat.format(totalAmountOwed)) getting executed twice if it enters in to the if loop. You have to add open and closing braces for else part also.

Basically you want to execute both lines code in the else part . Beacuse you did not add the opening and closing braces  in else logic , your second line will not work when condition is not satisfied